# What's going on about "mjsip"?

Tags: java, mobile, java-me, sip, mjsip

I have to build a SIP softphone on j2me platform. I found the mjsip2me project and tried to download it, but I try to access the http://mjsip.org and http://mjsipme.googlecode.com. It's not work. Why this project disappeared from the Internet?

Answer (score 1):

Look at here, [sip for java-me](http://java.net/projects/sip-for-me/) and [mjssip2me_11.6 for java-me.](http://www.codesworks.com/soft/sort014/sort016/sort076/down-20256.html)